# how to include sound in java

Tags: java, audio, jar

i have made a jar program that need to run an audio file
this is how i open the audio file(not in jar file)

```js
Thread sound = new Thread(){
  public void run(){
   MakeSound.playSound("Raef.wav");
  }
 };
```

i run it with

```js
sound.start();
```

and end it with

```js
sound.stop();
```

when i run it on blue j its worked but the sound isnt play on the jar files
can someone solve this ?
i need to make a program with jar

nb : MakeSound is another class i used to play the sound

```js
public class MakeSound {

    private static final int BUFFER_SIZE = 128000;
    private static File soundFile;
    private static AudioInputStream audioStream;
    private static AudioFormat audioFormat;
    private static SourceDataLine sourceLine;

    /**
     * @param filename the name of the file that is going to be played
     */
    public static void playSound(String filename){

        String strFilename = filename;

        // buka file
        try {
            soundFile = new File(strFilename);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.exit(1);
        }

        try {
            audioStream = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(soundFile);
        } catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.exit(1);
        }

        audioFormat = audioStream.getFormat();

        DataLine.Info info = new DataLine.Info(SourceDataLine.class, audioFormat);
        try {
            sourceLine = (SourceDataLine) AudioSystem.getLine(info);
            sourceLine.open(audioFormat);
        } catch (LineUnavailableException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.exit(1);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.exit(1);
        }

        sourceLine.start();

        int nBytesRead = 0;
        byte[] abData = new byte[BUFFER_SIZE];
        while (nBytesRead != -1) {
            try {
                nBytesRead = audioStream.read(abData, 0, abData.length);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            if (nBytesRead >= 0) {
                @SuppressWarnings("unused")
                int nBytesWritten = sourceLine.write(abData, 0, nBytesRead);
            }
        }

        sourceLine.drain();
        sourceLine.close();
    }
```

Comment: Is the audio file placed in the same directory as the .jar file?

Comment: im sorry i mean how to include sound in jar

Comment: yeah, i put that on the same directory...

Answer (score 0):

The exact steps to put an audio file in a jar depends on the IDE you are using.

What I normally do is to make a subfolder "audio" and put the audio files there. The subfolder is a subfolder of the code source.

Then, in the code, I create a URL that points to this subfolder.

```
URL url = this.getClass().getResource("audio/" + fileName);
```

I don't know about the specifics of MakeSound.playSound(). Hopefully it accepts a URL as a parameter. If it only accepts file names, you might need to rewrite it. Operating Systems generally aren't set up to find files that are packed in jars. URLs, though, are able to point inside of a jar.

Key point: the calling code is in a folder. I used "this" instead of invoking the class name of the calling code which is also possible. If this folder has a subfolder named "audio", the above line of code should find the file.

Comment: im sorry i forgot to mention that MakeSound is another class i used to play the sound, it works on the normal program, but when i convert to jar, it doesnt play the sound...

Comment: Good. So, along with the other things I mentioned in my answer, instead of audioStream = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(soundFile); do this audioStream = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(soundURL);

Comment: how can i use url for "soundFile = new File(strFilename);" it give an error message when i try to use url instead of string...

Comment: Show what you tried and the error message and I'll try to help. Or check out the api for URL constructor. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URL.html File won't work within a jar.

Comment: inconvertible types
required : java.lng.string; found : java.net.URL

what i change is:
public static void playSound(URL filename){

        String strFilename =(String) filename;

        // buka file
        try {
            soundURL = new File(strFilename);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.exit(1);
        }

        try {
            audioStream = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(soundURL);
and

Thread sound = new Thread(){
  public void run(){
   URL url = this.getClass().getResource("/Raef.wav");
   MakeSound.playSound(url);
  }
 };